# How to use array_diff_key properly?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array

```
array (
  500 => 
  array (
    1 => 1,
    6 => 2,
    2 => 1,
  ),
  550 => 
  array (
    3 => 1,
    6 => 2,
    4 => 1,
    5 => 1,
  ),
)
```

How could I get next result?

```
array(
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1,
    5 => 1,
)
```

I am trying to use `array_diff_key`/`array_intersect_key`, but can't get the goal.
Any suggestions?

Upd.

I don't need iterations. Direct `array_*` functions only.

Comment: The resulting array is impossible, because the same key is added twice.

Comment: the index 6 would be missing because of `array_diff_key`, the index 5 is missing, because you felt like it?

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the key difference of the union and the key intersection:

```
$array = array_diff_key(
    ($a = $array['500']) + ($b = $array['550']), 
    array_intersect_key($a, $b)
);
```

For your input array this give the desired output ([Demo](http://eval.in/14932)):

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array1 = array('blue'  => 1, 'red'  => 2, 'green'  => 3, 'purple' => 4);
$array2 = array('green' => 5, 'blue' => 6, 'yellow' => 7, 'cyan'   => 8);

var_dump(array_diff_key($array1, $array2));
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
array(2) {
  ["red"]=>
  int(2)
  ["purple"]=>
  int(4)
}
```

Reference
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're asking the impossible. Your final array contains two keys of equal value (and each key has the same value, coincidentally). An array must have keys of different values, or they will simply overwrite each other.

```
// impossible:
$ar = array(
  1 => 1,
  // ...
  1 => 1 // this value would overwrite the first
);
```

Having said that it's very difficult to understand what is the relationship between the first and second array, so I can't give a better answer.

EDIT: Scone's answer is correct (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15829227/932508).

You can get the final array with this line:

```
$finalArray = $forwardDiff + $backwardDiff;
```

Comment: Please review question.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
$foo = array (
  500 => 
  array (
    1 => 1,
    6 => 2,
    2 => 1,
  ),
  550 => 
  array (
    3 => 1,
    6 => 2,
    4 => 1,
    5 => 1,
  ),
);

$bar = array();
$forwardDiff = array_diff_key($foo[500], $foo[550]);
$backwardDiff = array_diff_key($foo[550], $foo[500])
foreach (array_merge($forwardDiff, $backwardDiff) as $key) {
  $bar = isset($foo[500][$key]) ? $foo[500][$key] : $foo[550][$key];
}
```

Edit: fix for wrong merging function..

Comment: Do not need iterations.

Comment: @Miraage you do need iterations. If any function does the iterations or you do the iterations by hand is not important.